# how to convert a hex value from a byte array as an interpreted ASCII number into an integer?

Tags: c#, integer, hex, ascii

I'm just starting with the c# programming and
as the heading describes, I'm looking for a way to convert a number passed to me as an ASCII character in a byte[] to an integer. I often find the way to convert a hex-byte to ASCII-char or string. I also find the other direction, get the hex-byte from a char. Maybe I should still say that I have the values displayed in a texbox for control.

as an example:
hex- code: **30 36 38 31**

Ascii string: **(0) 6 8 1**

Integer (dez) should be: **681**

so far I have tried all sorts of things. I also couldn't find it on the Microsoft Visual Studio website. Actually this should be relatively simple. I am sorry for my missing basics in c#.

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting together [this hex-to-string answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226433/c-sharp-convert-a-string-hex-to-ascii-string-reading-from-a-csv-file) and [this integer parsing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int), we get the following:

```
// hex -> byte array -> string
var hexBytes = "30 36 38 31";
var bytes = hexBytes.Split(' ')
    .Select(hb => Convert.ToByte(hb, 16)) // converts string -> byte using base 16
    .ToArray();
var asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

// parse string as integer
int x = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(asciiStr, out x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // write to console
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid integer.", asciiStr); // invalid number, write error to console
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/HGIZL38005)

Comment: thanks for your fast Help. I tryed it but i think there was a missunderstanding with byte[]. In fact, hexByte would have to be implemented in this way: byte[] hexBytes = [0x30, 0x36, 0x38, 0x31]; I get this byte[] from TCPIP with StreamReader.ReadBytes(). even if I change the answer from type byte[]  to var, I can't do any .Split operation.  As far as I know, in these case i don't have to. I also tryed to run through each byte individually, but  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(...) don`t accept a single byte.

Comment: @MaximilianFröhlich `var` won't make a difference because it will become `string` once compiled. [See here as an example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjSBAAyICGiAvIgEQAWApgDZ8A9hwDc1GjgBuTAE6IARm068BgsKPES6jAMZLu/IfA0wJuOgE5SAZQAuMgJYA7AOYA6VIKc6mt0h2k+AFceAGcALg4AGiYo+XJyMVNcAF9NWBSgA). `var` is syntactic sugar and the compiler works out what type it actually is at compile time.

Comment: _"`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(...)` don't accept a single byte."_ - Why are you trying to do it one byte at a time? Take my answer from `var asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);` downwards, replacing `bytes` with `hexBytes`: [example](https://rextester.com/LIIHY46083). Ultimately the cause for misunderstanding here is that you used the term "hex bytes", suggesting it was a `string`. A byte array is a byte array, regardless whether you initialize it with hex, octal, decimal. There is nothing special stored if you initialize it with hex.

Comment: Ok, I got it. My problem was how I read the data from TCPIP or how the data is split. The data now comes in as a byte array and can be used with var asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hexBytes); converted to a string. However, I still had to define a substring to remove a ":" before the values. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution of the problem is a *Linq query*. We should

1. `Split` initial string into items
2. `Convert` each item to int, treating item being hexadecimal. We should subtract `'0'` since we have not digit itself but its *ascii code*.
3. `Aggregate` items into the final integer

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

... 

string source = "30 36 38 31";

int result = source
  .Split(' ')
  .Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item, 16) - '0')
  .Aggregate((sum, item) => sum * 10 + item);
```

If you want to obtain ascii `string` you can

1. `Split` the string
2. `Convert` each item into `char`
3. `Join` the chars back to string:

**Code:**

```
string source = "30 36 38 31";

string asciiString = string.Join(" ", source
  .Split(' ')
  .Select(item => (char)Convert.ToInt32(item, 16)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a byte array containing ASCII codes to an integer:

```
byte[] data   = {0x30, 0x36, 0x38, 0x31};
string str    = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
int    number = int.Parse(str);

Console.WriteLine(number); // Prints 681
```

To convert an integer to a 4-byte array containing ASCII codes (only works if the number is <= 9999 of course):

```
int number = 681;
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(number.ToString("D4"));
// data[] now contains 30h, 36h, 38h, 31h

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", data.Select(b => b.ToString("x"))));
```